# Maven nexus dependency resolution problem

Tags: java, spring, maven, nexus

I have created two mirrors for my nexus internal repo, because openshift has problems without it. The problem is that I'm getting error `Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4 in team-internal-repo-mirror2 (http://10.0.2.156/content/reposi tories/releases)` and I have defined both 3rd party and releases repos in the settings file

````
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>team-internal-repo-mirror1</id>
            <mirrorOf>Nexus third party</mirrorOf>
            <!-- Must match repository id. -->
            <name>Dummy mirror to unblock the team repo server</name>
            <url>http://10.0.2.156/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
            <!-- <blocked>false</blocked> -->
            <!-- This is not needed, the mirror is unblocked by default. -->
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>team-internal-repo-mirror2</id>
            <mirrorOf>releases</mirrorOf>
            <!-- Must match repository id. -->
            <name>Dummy mirror to unblock the team repo server</name>
            <url>http://10.0.2.156/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <!-- <blocked>false</blocked> -->
            <!-- This is not needed, the mirror is unblocked by default. -->
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>releases</id>
          <url>http://10.0.2.156/content/repositories/releases</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>Nexus third party</id>
          <url>http://10.0.2.156/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>        
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>```
Thanks in advance
````

Comment: There is a space in `http://10.0.2.156/content/reposi tories/releases` on the error message is this real error msg or typo in your question?